# Calculate date based on period in php/joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Anyone knows how to calculate date based on number of week/Month/Year?

suppose if i set the period as 2 weeks, I should get the date 2 week after the current date. If the period is 3 weeks, then, I should get 3 week after current date. Similarly for month and year as well. Can anybody please help with reference code? I am not able to implement this. 
Is there any predefined function for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to get, but take a look at this [answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5233/is-there-a-joomla-function-to-determine-the-last-fiscal-quarter/5234#5234) at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) to see the PHP-esque date calculations that are possible.  It's about quarters, but with variations like [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) uses, you should be able to get what you need.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");// current date

$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +30 days");
```